# WinRM / WSMan - getting SSL handshake error / TCP RST when connecting with IP address, correct connection when connecting with hostname

Tags: ansible, windows

While using Ansible to manage some AWS based Windows machines, when connecting using the IP as destination, on some machines I'm getting an SSL Error

> credssp: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='18.217.233.26', port=5986): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(\"bad
>   handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')\",),))", "unreachable":
>   true}

In wireshark it looks like TCP RST is sent by server

When connecting using hostname or FQDN the connection succeeds.

I don't see any relevant log in the event logs on WSMan side.

Anybody have any experience with setting up winrm for Ansible and can assist?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error .. You probably want to run [ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1) script with `-ForceNewSSLCert` option on your remote machines.

```
.\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 -ForceNewSSLCert
```

Comment: Also, when logged in to remote machine
 Run as  Admin Powershell:
$ winrm qc
To check how your machine is currently setup.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesnt work, check your TLS1.3 registry key  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server`

The actual error for me was TLS 1.3 was set enabled (1), in registry, but was not set DisabledByDefault.  setting that to 1 resolved the long looming ansible ssl connection error.

You can also delete the TLS1.3 key, so that its not explicitly set.

```
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_scheme: https
ansible_port: 5986 #didnt break it, leaving this enabled
ansible_winrm_cert_pem: ..
ansible_winrm_cert_key_pem: ...
ansible_winrm_transport: certificate
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore # maybe because i WAS USING IP, not hostname, also the cert  CN is "ansible" anyway, not matching any hostname.
```

https://community.tenable.com/s/article/How-to-view-and-change-the-Windows-Registry-Settings-for-the-SSL-TLS-Protocols-on-a-Windows-Host